# Custom Button and Target return value

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a custom Button class.  I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it to recognize taps and respond as needed:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
self.recognizer = recognizer;
[buttonView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

I create the button and add a target:

```
[buttonList addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonListSelected)];

-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    [self.recognizer addTarget:target action:action];
}
```

When I create the action method and ask it to return the class:

```
-(void)buttonSortSelected:(SubButton *)subButton {}
```

It returns the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Can I set it up so the custom class will return `self` instead of the recognizer?

Comment: The gesture recognizer has a reference to the view it was added to, what else do you need ?

Comment: Cleaner and simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the parameters you have to handle to `tapDetected:` by yourself.

```
// In your custom button class

-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    self.target = target;
    self.targetedSelector = selector;
}
```

Then

```
// In your custom button class

- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   [self.target performSelector:self.targetedSelector withObject:self];
}
```

Comment: you're welcome ;) can you please validate the answer ?